# Swing - JTree addTreeSelectionListener invoked on node delete

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am new to swings, sorry if it's an expected behaviour.

I have a DeleteAll button, which deletes all JTree nodes. It's working fine.

But I am wondering why 'addTreeSelectionListener' is invoked if i select a node then i click on DeleteAll button.

Please suggest how to avoid this ?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
    import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
    import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

    public class JTreeDemo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JTreeFrame();
                    frame.setTitle("JTree Demo");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class JTreeFrame extends JFrame {
        public JTreeFrame() {
            setSize(300, 300);

            DefaultMutableTreeNode country = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Animal");

            DefaultMutableTreeNode state = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Tiger");
            country.add(state);

            JButton deleteAll = new JButton("DeleteAll");
            JTree tree = new JTree(country);

            deleteAll.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        System.out.println("Delete started...");

                        DefaultTreeModel ttmodel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
                        //ttmodel.setRoot(null);
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode troot = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) ttmodel.getRoot();
                        troot.removeAllChildren();
                        ttmodel.reload();
                    }
                }
            );

            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(e -> {
                TreePath path = e.getPath();
                System.out.println(path);
            });

            JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                    deleteAll, new JScrollPane(tree));

            add(new JScrollPane(splitPane));
        }
     }
```

Comment: You a node was selected, then deleted, the selection has changed...

Comment: ya, i guessed so, how can we avoid it ?

Comment: That would depend. The simply solution would be to remove the listener before you delete the nodes and re-added it, a more complicated solution would be to use a flag which would force the listener to ignore changes while it's set

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, instead of handling with flags, removing and add listener would be easy. Will try this.